# Phonegap + Webservice

Tags: android, asp.net, jquery, cordova, mobile

I have a index.html with an ajax call to a webservice(ASP.NET) that works fine when i deploy it on the bigrock server(i have a domain).

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "myurl/mywebservice.asmx",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            alert("success");
        },
        error: function (msg,status) {
           $('#demo').html("status is "+status+" . Msg is "+msg.d.responseText);
           //attribute for responsetext might be wrong here but in my application it is correct as i am using different system ryt now.
        }
    });
```

But when i used the online zipper of phonegap to make a apk for my android app from the html, css,js,web.config,few class and installed it on my device...nothing comes up. Its shows me an ajax error with no responseText.

What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you zip up your assets to submit to PhoneGap Build, you need to include a [config.xml file](https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml) and specify access policy similar to

```
<access origin="https://your.domain.com" />
```

This will instruct PhoneGap to allow communication with your server.

Comment: this dnt help me...moreover i am not able to debug it...any idea how to debug the app installed in device..

Comment: PhoneGap has a debug service available at http://debug.phonegap.com/. This is powered by [weinre] (http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/). There are external services available like [spotneedle] (http://spotneedle.com) and [jsconsole] (http://jsconsole.com) which might be helpful too.

Comment: i tried debugging through debug.phonegap.com...unfortunately for mobile device there is no output in console and no device is shown...i guess my application is not able to access internet from my device...is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

When your app is deployed to the device using PhoneGap, your "Home" location becomes the file-system on the local device.

This means any ajax calls are cross-domain calls which require further configuration to setup correctly.

See [this question for potential answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990907/same-origin-policy-on-mobile-apps)

Comment: I have idea about the cross domain, but i dnt know how to solve it...and that too we i am using the online phonegap zipper.

Comment: This offers a good solution if you control the service too:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010028/wcf-rest-with-jquery-ajax-removing-working-around-same-origin-policy?rq=1

Comment: using that i can solve my problem but not on my mobile device....i am looking for the solution for my android device...